# making android views in runtime

Tags: java, android

I'm importing a windows pairs game (writen in java) to android
but when I run this I can see no buttons...
(currently my code does not seems nice cuz I shoud deliver it to uni fast)

what is going wrong here?

```
package mgh;

import mgh.mgh.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class mghActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         new mghActivity();
    }



    public int numberOfClickes=0;
    public card continueCard=null;
    public int killedCards=0;
    public card selectedCard=null;
    public long spentTime=0;
    public card[][] card=new card[4][4];


    public void mghActivity(){

        setTitle("pairs");
        //setVisible(true);
        //setSize(500,500 );
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        AbsoluteLayout lay=new AbsoluteLayout(this);

        int[] clr=new int[8];
        short[] timesUsed=new short[8];
        for (int i=0;i<=7;i++) 
            timesUsed[i]=0;
        for (int i=0;i<=7;i++)
            clr[i]= Color.rgb(((int)(Math.random()*2))*255,
                             ((int)(Math.random()*2))*255,
                             ((int)(Math.random()*2))*255);
        for (int i=0;i<=3;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<=3;j++){
                int rnd=0;
                while (timesUsed[rnd]>=2)
                    rnd=(int)(Math.random()*8)%8;
                timesUsed[rnd]++;
                card[i][j]=new card(this,clr[rnd]);

                //card[i][j].setEnabled(false);

                 //AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams mparams=new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams
                 //(lay.getWidth()/4,lay.getHeight()/4,(lay.getWidth()/4)*i,(lay.getWidth()/4)*j);


             int m=40;
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams mparams=new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams 
          (m,m,m*i,m*j);
                            lay.addView(card[i][j],mparams);

                    card[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

                }
            setContentView(lay);



        }


        public void onClick(View arg0) {


    }
}

class card extends Button {///not completed
    public int color;
    public card(Context context,int color){
        super(context);
        this.color=color;
        setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your [`AbsoluteLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) - which is a class that has been deprecated _forever_, btw - has 0 width and height until it's laid out on-screen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0

Comment: thank u .understood

Comment: Oh, yeah, Mark has a good point in their answer below, too. I didn't notice the `new` keyword there. That just will not work. You need to call the method, not try to instantiate the `Activity`, which you cannot do, and have it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method onCreate, you just new `mghActivity` but did not call the the method `mghActivity`. And `mghActivity` is not a constructor. You shall remove the `void` before `mghActivity`. Then it will be a constructor and called automatically. Even so, I will not recommend creating an Activity like this.

Comment: thanks, now it force closes... AbsoluteLayout is deprecated...does it matters?(my emulator is running android 2.1)

Comment: Or you do not use 'new' and just call the method mghActivity() with that void